# What type of groups does Microsoft's U-Prove use (Schnorr... etc?)

Tags: group-theory, u-prove

I'm trying to learn more about the Subgroups implementation of Microsoft UProve.   I'm unsure if they are [Schnorr Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) or use a different foundation?

Can anyone point me to the technical reading required to understand the implementation?  (anything appropriate for a determined, yet fledgling novice would be appreciated)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[U-Prove Recommended Parameters](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=166972) describes the groups used by U-Prove.

For the subgroup variant it references Appendix A.1.1.3 of FIPS186-3 which is about groups for finite-field based DSA. AFAIK these groups are Schnorr groups, even though NIST never refers to them as such.

The ECC variant uses standard NIST curves such as P-256, P-384 and P-521.